# Global parameters for trigger body properties and using split function on @triggerbody().folderpath

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-pipelines, azure-data-factory

I am trying to pass into a parameter via a event trigger the folder path of the blob storage container @triggerbody().folderpath .

I have created a pipeline parameter called folderPath which is equal to  @triggerbody().folderpath

[image]

I then created a variable within the pipeline as BusinessUnit and used the variable @{split(pipeline().parameters.folderPath,'/')[3]}

This returns the 'Business Unit'
i.e. BI\DEV\BusinessUnit

[image]

What I want to achieve is the ability to use this folderPath (parameter) and BusinessUnit (variable) in other pipelines. However, I am struggling to capture the @triggerbody().folderpath into a global parameter.

Also, there is global variables. The @{split(pipeline().parameters.folderPath,'/')[3]} gives me the correct value as the BusinessUnit variable.

An alternative is to have this as a parameter rather than a variable. However, I can't seem to get the split function to work here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In ADF we have a **[Global Parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/author-global-parameters)** which you can access using Manage tab in ADF Studio, however these can only store **constants** across a Data Factory that can be consumed by a pipeline in any expression.

As you can see below, I have set the Global parameter value to the pipeline parameter that store the value received from the trigger.

[image]

In turn, since these parameter's (`@pipeline().parameters.folderpath`) scope is limited to their pipelines, until you have a parameter with same name and value in other pipelines, this will throw an error! If you have a same parameter and value in another pipeline then there is no need for using a global parameter!

[image]

[image]

[image]

### Workaround.....

Using execute pipeline activity to invoke another pipeline in which you want to use this data.

1. add parameters in the parent pipeline
2. add parameters in the child pipeline
3. and now pass the parameters from parents to child while selecting
   the child pipeline.

create parameter...

[image]

Get value from trigger...

[image]

Use/set trigger value in parameter...

[image]

Create Parameter in the other pipeline to hold input from parent pipeline...

[image]

From **parent pipeline** in **Execute Pipeline activity** pass the local parameter value..

[image]

use received parameter as necessary....

[image]

You can similarly use variable and then pass them to parameter.

[image]

**Another method** could be a web activity that gets the pipeline parameter value and  using ADF SDK or REST API, you pass that to the next Execute Pipeline activity. See [Parameterizing the Execute Pipeline activity](https://richardswinbank.net/adf/parameterising_the_execute_pipeline_activity)

Comment: Can the workaround be done for variables? For example, if I capture the folder path into a parameter and then split it into a variable. Can this then be passed on through the pipelines?

Comment: yes, that is what I have tried to show in the last screenshot

Comment: In the parent pipeline: https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHbcX.png

Comment: If I am passing the variable into the child parameter across multiple pipelines. Can I call all of these as child_BusinessUnit or will this error. Basically, do each of them need a unique name or can I just refer to it as child_BusinessUnit across all the pipelines

Comment: As they are local to that pipeline. You can refer the same name as long as they are all in different pipelines.